# How to find multiple in C#

Tags: c#

how might I find out, in an if statement, weather the specified int is a multiple of 5? This is what I mean:

```
if(X [is a multiple of] 5)
{
    Console.Writeline("Yes");
}
```

What would be [is a multiple of]?

Also, why is it that when I do:

```
if(X = 5)
{
    Console.Writeline("sdjfdslf");
}
```

it shows "X = 5" in red and tells me "Can not implicitly convert type "int" to "bool"? I am using X as an input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how might I find out, in an if statement, weather the specified int is a multiple of 5?

You want to use the modulo operation (%).

```
if (X % 5 == 0) {
    Console.Writeline("Yes");
}
```

> it shows "X = 5" in red and tells me "Can not implicitly convert type "int" to "bool"? I am using X as an input.

The single equals `=` is assignment. You want the double equals `==` to do a check for equality.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (x % 5 == 0) Console.WriteLine("yes");
```

C# [mod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) operator

Also use `==` to return a boolean value for a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulus operator (%), which returns the remainder after division:

```
if (X % 5 == 0) { Console.Writeline("Yes"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

= is the assignment operator, while == is used for comparison.

So when your write `if (X = 5)`, you're assigning 5 to X and treat that as a boolean expression.

Interestingly, assigning a value to a variable also returns the value itself.

```
y = x = 5
```

assigns 5 to x and assigns the result of (x = 5), which is also 5, to y.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the modulo operator (%) to determine if an integer is a multiple of another integer, like so:

```
if (x % 5 == 0)
```

To answer the second part of your question (`if (x = 5)`), a single equals sign is an assignment operator in C#.  You should be using the double equals sign instead, which is the comparison operator, like so:  `if (x == 5)`.